# How to develop an Android APP to transfer pictures with a USB device?

Tags: android, usb

I want to develop an Android APP to transfer pictures with USB device. And I have finished the development of Android User Interface, the connection with USB device by Android USB API according official guide (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host).

But when I try to transfer data with the device, the guide just provides only one function : bulkTransfer(). So I don't know how to do next because I just only have Android developing experience.

Then I search in the github and find a lib-libaums is awesome. But I don't know the theory under this project.

Is there some tutorial to help me to develop the remain part of my APP? Or is there some theoretical guide to help me to develop a simple version of libaums? @Magnus

Comment: Why cant you use bulkTransfer?

Comment: And what kind of usb device is it that you coonect to your Android device? A usb-stick? A usb-drive(). Which protocol should be used?